# Calculating working minutes for Normal and Night Shift

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am making a query to fetch the working minutes for employees. The problem I have is the Night Shift. I know that I need to subtract the "ShiftStartMinutesFromMidnight" but I can't find the right logic.

**NOTE:** I can't changing the database, I only can use the data from it.

Let's say I have these records.

```
+----+--------------------------+----------+
| ID |        EventTime         | ReaderNo |
-----+--------------------------+----------+
|  1 |  2019-12-04 11:28:46.000 |    In    |
|  1 |  2019-12-04 12:36:17.000 |    Out   |
|  1 |  2019-12-04 12:39:23.000 |    In    |
|  1 |  2019-12-04 12:51:21.000 |    Out   |
|  1 |  2019-12-05 07:37:49.000 |    In    |
|  1 |  2019-12-05 08:01:22.000 |    Out   |
|  2 |  2019-12-04 22:11:46.000 |    In    |
|  2 |  2019-12-04 23:06:17.000 |    Out   |
|  2 |  2019-12-04 23:34:23.000 |    In    |
|  2 |  2019-12-05 01:32:21.000 |    Out   |
|  2 |  2019-12-05 01:38:49.000 |    In    |
|  2 |  2019-12-05 06:32:22.000 |    Out   |
-----+--------------------------+----------+
```

```
WITH CT AS (SELECT
            EIn.PSNID, EIn.PSNNAME
                ,CAST(DATEADD(minute, -0, EIn.EventTime) AS date) AS dt
                ,EIn.EventTime AS LogIn
                ,CA_Out.EventTime AS LogOut
                ,DATEDIFF(minute, EIn.EventTime, CA_Out.EventTime) AS WorkingMinutes
            FROM
                VIEW_EVENT_EMPLOYEE AS EIn
                CROSS APPLY
            (
                SELECT TOP(1) EOut.EventTime
                    FROM VIEW_EVENT_EMPLOYEE AS EOut
                    WHERE
                        EOut.PSNID = EIn.PSNID
                        AND EOut.ReaderNo = 'Out'
                        AND EOut.EventTime >= EIn.EventTime
                    ORDER BY EOut.EventTime
                ) AS CA_Out
            WHERE
                 EIn.ReaderNo = 'In'    
                )
            SELECT
                PSNID
                ,PSNNAME
                ,dt
                ,LogIn
                ,LogOut
                ,WorkingMinutes
            FROM CT
            WHERE dt BETWEEN '2019-11-29' AND '2019-12-05'
            ORDER BY LogIn 
            ;
```

**OUTPUT FROM QUERY**

```
+----+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------------+
| ID |    date    |          In             |         Out             | WorkingMinutes |
-----+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------------+
|  1 | 2019-12-04 | 2019-12-04 11:28:46.000 | 2019-12-04 12:36:17.000 |             68 |
|  1 | 2019-12-04 | 2019-12-04 12:39:23.000 | 2019-12-04 12:51:21.000 |             12 |
|  1 | 2019-12-05 | 2019-12-05 07:37:49.000 | 2019-12-05 08:01:22.000 |             24 |
-----+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------------+
```

I was thinking something like this. When `Out` is between 06:25 - 6:40. But I also need to check If employee, **previous** day has `In` between 21:50 - 22:30. I need that second condition because some employee from first shift maybe can `Out`, for example at 6:30.
*(1310 is the ShiftStartMinutesFromMidnight

**Line 3 of Query**

```
CAST(DATEADD(minute, -0, EIn.EventTime) AS date) AS dt
```

**Updating the Line 3 with this code.**

```
CASE 
WHEN CAST(CA_Out.LogDate AS time) BETWEEN '06:25:00' AND '06:40:00' 
AND CAST(EIn.LogDate AS time) BETWEEN '21:50:00' AND '22:30:00' THEN CAST(DATEADD(minute, -1310, EIn.LogDate) AS date) 
ELSE CAST(DATEADD(minute, -0, EIn.LogDate) AS date) 
END as dt
```

**Expected Output**

```
+----+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------------+
| ID |     date   |          In             |         Out             | WorkingMinutes |
-----+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------------+
|  2 | 2019-12-04 | 2019-12-04 22:11:46.000 | 2019-12-04 23:06:17.000 |             55 |
|  2 | 2019-12-04 | 2019-12-04 23:34:23.000 | 2019-12-05 01:32:21.000 |            118 |
|  2 | 2019-12-04 | 2019-12-05 01:38:49.000 | 2019-12-05 06:32:22.000 |            294 |
-----+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Does you really need minutes for each separate in-out pair? or daily minutes sum is enough? And check "Expected Output" values - they are too strange... 118 minutes from '2019-12-04 23:34:23.000' till midnight...

Comment: Does day shift could turn into night shift?
if night shift is from 20:00 - 06:00 and worker works from 12:00 till 23:30 does in that period 12:00 - 20:00 is day shift and after, from 20:00 - 23:30 is night shift?

Comment: @Akina Daily minutes sum is enough. 118 minutes is OK `Out  - In (2019-12-05 01:32:21.000 - 2019-12-04 23:34:23.000)` is that how I get, not till midnight.

Comment: @Strauteka No, night shift is only from 22:00 to 6:00. All others are normal or day shifts. The last day shift finish at 22:30 and that is fixed.

Comment: if it comes to detailed info,
You can calculate exact minutes of workers night shift and day shift in in/out period not assuming that he is working exact shift.
So this adds columns DayWorkingMinutes, NightWorkingMinutes and then understand what to do with this info.
You can't rely on workers arrival time, if he arrives earlier than you hard-coded?

Comment: @Strauteka How can I calculate, let's say if worker has worked on 31.01.2020 starting at 22:00 and finished on 01.02.2020 at 06:00. I need that 6 hours to be calculated in January, not in Feb.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that total minutes per separate date is enough:

```sql
WITH 
/* enumerate pairs */
cte1 AS ( SELECT *, 
                 COUNT(CASE WHEN ReaderNo = 'In' THEN 1 END) 
                     OVER (PARTITION BY ID 
                           ORDER BY EventTime) pair
          FROM test ),
/* divide by pairs */
cte2 AS ( SELECT ID, MIN(EventTime) starttime, MAX(EventTime) endtime
          FROM cte1
          GROUP BY ID, pair ),
/* get dates range */
cte3 AS ( SELECT CAST(MIN(EventTime) AS DATE) minDate,
                 CAST(MAX(EventTime) AS DATE) maxDate
          FROM test),
/* generate dates list */
cte4 AS ( SELECT minDate theDate
          FROM cte3
          UNION ALL
          SELECT DATEADD(dd, 1, theDate)
          FROM cte3, cte4
          WHERE theDate < maxDate ),
/* add overlapped dates to pairs */
cte5 AS ( SELECT ID, starttime, endtime, theDate
          FROM cte2, cte4 
          WHERE theDate BETWEEN CAST(starttime AS DATE) AND  CAST(endtime AS DATE) ),
/* adjust borders */
cte6 AS ( SELECT ID, 
                 CASE WHEN starttime < theDate
                      THEN theDate
                      ELSE starttime
                      END starttime,
                 CASE WHEN CAST(endtime AS DATE) > theDate
                      THEN DATEADD(dd, 1, theDate)
                      ELSE endtime
                      END endtime,
                 theDate
          FROM cte5 )
/* calculate total minutes per date */
SELECT ID,
       theDate,
       SUM(DATEDIFF(mi, starttime, endtime)) workingminutes
FROM cte6
GROUP BY ID, 
         theDate
ORDER BY 1,2
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=696dd620ffe1174f5cc864b7dda964c9)

The solution is specially made detailed, step by step, so that you can easily understand the logic.

You may freely combine some CTEs into one. You may also use pre-last `cte5` combined with `cte2` if you need the output strongly as shown.

The solution assumes that none records are lost in source data (each 'In' matches strongly one 'Out' and backward, and no adjacent or overlapped pairs).

Comment: That's not what I need, I already have that  solution with my query. I need: If a worker has worked from 04.12 - 21:50 to 05.12 - 6:00 to calculate that worker has worked "exac minutes" on 04.12. That's why I need to subtract "ShiftStartMinutesFromMidnight" in my case -1310 minutes to get the Expected output

Comment: @ValentinGjorgoski I.e. in this case all worker's minutes must be referenced to 04.12? And what is 1310 minutes - the amount of minutes from 04.12 - 21:50 till 05.12 - 6:00 is 490, it seems.

Comment: 1310 like the name say's "ShiftStartMinutesFromMidnight", because shift starts at 
21:50 (21*60 + 50 = 1310 minutes) that I subtract from EventTime.
More about at: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/131021/split-date-time-value-for-night-shift-employee

Comment: @ValentinGjorgoski I.e. simply `ShiftStartMinutesFromMidnight = DATEDIFF(MI, CAST(EventTime AS DATE), EventTime)` (or backward if you need negative value)? But if so what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know where you stopped but here is how I do,
Night shift 20:00 - 05:00 so in one day 00:00 - 5:00; 22:00 - 24:00
day shift  5:00 - 22:00

To get easier overlapping checking you need to change all dates to unix timestamp. so you don't have to split time intervals like shown above

So generate map of each period work for fetch period date_from and date_till, make sure to add holiday and pre-holiday exceptions where periods are different
something like:
Unix values is only for understanding.

```
unix_from_tim, unix_till_tim, shift_type
1580680800, 1580680800, 1  => example 02-02-2020:22:00:00, 03-02-2020:05:00:00, 1
1580680800, 1580680800, 0 => example 03-02-2020:05:00:00, 03-02-2020:22:00:00, 0
1580680800, 1580680800, 1 => example 03-02-2020:22:00:00, 04-02-2020:05:00:00, 1
```

...
Make sure you don't calculate overlapping minutes on period start/end..

And there is worker one row 
with unix_from_tim, unix_from_tim

```
1580680800, 1580680800=> something like 02-02-2020:16:30:00, 03-02-2020:07:10:00
```

When you check overlapping you can get ms like this:

> MIN(work_period:till,worker_period:till) - MAX(work_period:from, worker_period:from);

example in simple numbers:
work_period 3 - 7
worker_period 5 - 12
MIN(7,12) - MAX(3,5) = 7 - 5 = 2 //overlap

work_period 3 - 7
worker_period 8 - 12
MIN(7,12) - MAX(3,8) = 7 - 8 = -1 //if negative not overlap!

work_period 3 - 13
worker_period 8 - 12
MIN(13,12) - MAX(3,8) = 13 - 8 = 5 //full overlap!

And you have to check each worker period on all overlaping time generated work intervals.
May be someone can make select where you don't have to generate work_shift overlapping but its not a easy task if you add more holidays, transferred days, reduced time days etc.

Hope it helps